# save the song in iphone through application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have completed the code to play song using url connection..
now how can i save it in iphone.

thnx

Answer (score 4):

If by saying "save it in iPhone" you mean "save it in the iPod app" (i.e. Music Library), it is unfortunately not possible, as Apple does not allow external apps to add files to the system's Libraries on iPhone. (Video, Music, Podcast, etc)

If by saying "save it in iPhone" you mean "put the app on iPhone", you will need the latest XCode and an iPhone Developer Account, which you can purchase at developer.apple.com

If by saying "save it in iPhone" you mean "save the file inside the app", you will need to get a persistent storage within the app (Core Data or dictionary) to be able to access the files after you quit the app, and find your way to store the data on the device (you can compress them as zip files, save away in a directory, add to a dictionary, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't save songs to the iPod library, but you can save the song locally in the app. The easiest way to do this would be to implement Core Data storage and partition a portion of your app's footprint for the song.

Comment: Did any of these answer your question? They are all pretty thorough answers so if you wouldn't mind, a lot of us would be thankful if you would take the time to select the most helpful and accept it.